# Show that $A$ is invertible and that $AB=BA$

Tags: matrices

Let $A,B\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

We suppose that there exists $P\in\mathbb{R}[X]$ with $\deg P\geq1$ such that $P(0)=1,P(A)=AB$.

How can I show that $A$ is invertible and that $AB=BA$ ?

I don't really see how to exploit the information given here to get to the answer, especially $P(0)=1$.. All I have tried haven't worked up to now.

Comment: Is the identity $I+AQ(A)=AB$ more suggestive? (By the way, the exercise does not make much sense if $n\ne p$, you might want to check this.)

Comment: @Did That doesn't ring any bell. What is $Q$ here ?

Comment: Maybe 12 seconds (typing included) is a period of intensive reflexion which can be extended a little...

Comment: @Did Oh, I thought you were asking if I knew of any identity related to something like $I+AQ(A)=AB$. My bad. And yes sorry, $n=p$ (edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P(X)=a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2+\dots+a_nX^n$, then you have $1=P(0)=a_0$ and $AB=P(A)=a_0+a_1A+\dots+a_nA^n$.

So $AB -1=A(a_1+a_2A+\dots+a_nA^{n-1})=AM$ for some matrix $M$, or $A(B-M)=I_n$ which gives invertibility of $A$.

Since you have also $(B-M)A=I_n$ and $AM=MA$, you get $AB-AM=BA-MA$ which gives $AB=BA$.

Comment: Why exactly do we have $AM=MA$ ?

Comment: $M$ is defined as $M=a_1+a_2A+\dots+a_nA^{n-1}$ a sum and product of $A$'s which comute with $A$.

Answer (score 3):

Let us put $Q(X)=P(X)-P(0)=P(X)-1$ , then $X$ divides $Q$ and $Q(X)=XT(X)$ for some polynom $T$

Since $P(A)=AB$ we have $Q(A)=AB-I_n$ thus: $$AT(A)=AB-I_n$$  thus $$A(B-T(A))=I_n$$

That gives $A$  invertible and $A^{-1}=B-T(A)$

(it's known if a matrix is right or left invertible then it's invertible)

We have also :  $B=T(A)+A^{-1}$  Then  $AB=BA=AT(A)+I_n$

(one can remark that $AT(A)=T(A)A$ since $T(A)$ is  a pololynom of $A$)